# How to get the area under a histogram in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, area

I have been plotting a histogram. My code looks like this:

```
x0=-15000
x1=15000
b=np.arange(x0,x1,(x1-x0)/250.)

plt.plot(b[0:-1], plt.hist(non_zeros(-e[0]), bins=b, normed=1, visible=0)[0], color = "k", label=r'$\gamma$ = 1.0')
```

I normed the histogram so the area under the curve is equal to 1.  e[0] is just some data i take in from a document.

What i want now is to double check that the are under the histogram is equal to one. How can this be done?

Comment: Can you add some code so that people trying to help you can actually run the code?  Include your imports, define `non_zeros`, give an example value for `e[0]`.

Comment: Just a comment on your code, Python has proper True and False constants for booleans which are preferred above 1 and 0 (so you'd have `normed=True, visible=False` rather than what you have).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integrate histogram in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29974976/integrate-histogram-in-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can calculate the area in this way:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = numpy.random.randn(1000)

values, bins, _ = plt.hist(x, normed=True)
area = sum(numpy.diff(bins)*values)
```

Comment: Thanx a lot chthonicdaemon,

Is it also possible to find the 0.5% and 99.5% quantile?

Comment: You can use [`numpy.percentile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html) to calculate percentiles.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x0=-15000
x1=15000
b=np.arange(x0,x1,(x1-x0)/250.)
values, bins, patches = plt.hist(b, 20 ,range=[-15000,15000], facecolor='green',normed=0, alpha=0.5)

#simply here you need to have the lenght of your bins to have a probability for under the graph

len_bins= len(bins)-1
#here is the totaly area under your histogram, which is supposed to be 1 as you want = suming up all the values for of all bins
Total_Area= sum(values[0:len_bins])/sum(values)
#so now lets say you want to have half of the area
Half_Area= sum(values[0:len_bins/2])/sum(values)
```