# Integrate histogram in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, integral

Is there a simple command in matplotlib that let's me take the integral of histogram over a certain range? If I plot a histogram with:
     fig = plt.hist(x, bins)
Then, is there a command like fig.integral(bin1, bin2)? That will return the integral of the histogram from bin1 to bin2?

Comment: You really should provide a minimal example so we know what your variables are. Specifically, what is `bins`? If it's an integer, then you can use my answer but if not you need something more flexible like what cphlewis posted

Comment: `hist` now has a `cumulative` keyword to plot the cumulative.  Not sure if you wanted the values or just the plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, remember that the integral is just the total area underneath the curve. In the case of a histogram, the integral (in pseudo-python) is `sum([bin_width[i] * bin_height[i] for i in bin_indexes_to_integrate])`.

As a reference, see this example of using a histogram in matplotlib: http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/histogram_demo.html.

Here they separate the output of the `plt.histogram` into three parts, `n`, `bins`, and `patches`. We can use this separation to implement the "integral" you request like so.

Assuming `bin1` and `bin2` are indexes of the bins you want to integrate, then calculate the integral like so:

```
# create some dummy data to make a histogram of
import numpy as np
x = np.random.randn(1000)
nbins = 10
# use _ to assign the patches to a dummy variable since we don't need them
n, bins, _ = plt.hist(x, nbins)

# get the width of each bin
bin_width = bins[1] - bins[0]
# sum over number in each bin and mult by bin width, which can be factored out
integral = bin_width * sum(n[bin1:bin2])
```

If you've defined `bins` to be a list with multiple widths, you have to do something like what @cphlewis said (this works w/ no off by one):

```
integral = sum(np.diff(bins[bin1:bin2])*n[bin1:bin2])
```

It's also worth taking a look at the [API documentation for matplotlib.pyplot.hist](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist).

Comment: I think this only works for adjacent bins? (esp. as they needn't all be of the same width?)

Comment: OP says they want to take integral from/to bin1 and bin2.  I'd assumed `bins` was an integer, but you're right if it's a list with different widths this wouldn't work.

Comment: It wasn't clear to me that bin1 and bin2 are adjacent, like `bins[1]` and bins[2]` would be, or just argument names 1 and 2. @Jess, be careful if integrating over a distance or over irregular bins.

Comment: I had to slightly change the formula to avoid an off-by-one error. This worked for me: `integral = sum(np.diff(bins[bin1:bin2+1])*n[bin1:bin2])`

Answer (score 2):

The `plt.hist` command returns all the data you need to make one. If `out = plt.hist(...)`, the bin heights are in `out[0]` and the bin widths are `diff(out[1])`. E.g.,

```
sum(out[0][4:7]*diff(out[1][4:8]))
```

for the integral over bins 4-6 inclusive. `diff` calculates each bin-width, so it handles bins of different widths, and the multiplication happens element-wise, so calculates the areas of each rectangle in the histogram.